# C++: Scope of templated base class?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, scope

This code does not compile:

```
template <typename T>
struct B {
    typedef T type;
};

struct D0 : public B<int> {
    void h(type) { }
};

template <typename T>
struct D : public B<T> {
    void f(typename B<T>::type) { }
    void g(type) { }
};
```

- http://ideone.com/pVh94t

Specifically, although `D0::h(type)` and `D::f(typename B<T>::type)` compile, `D::g(type)` does not.  Why is `type` not visible in `D`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer can be found in two places. First C++11 draft standard [`N3337`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf):

§14.6.2/3

> In the definition of a class template or a member of a class template,
>   if a base class of the class template depends on a *template-parameter*,
>   the **base class scope is not examined during unqualified name lookup**
>   either at the point of definition of the class template or member or
>   during an instantiation of the class template or member. [ *Example:*
>
> ```
> typedef double A;
> template<class T> class B {
>   typedef int A;
> };
> template<class T> struct X : B<T> {
>   A a;              // a has type double
> };
> ```
>
> The type name `A` in the definition of `X<T>` binds to the typedef
>   name defined in the global namespace scope, not to the typedef name
>   defined in the base class `B<T>`. — *end example* ]

<sup>(Bold emphasis mine)</sup>

Second, the parashift FAQ provides a human-readable explanation in [Why am I getting errors when my template-derived-class uses a nested type it inherits from its template-base-class?](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#nondependent-name-lookup-types):

> Perhaps surprisingly, the following code is not valid C++, even though
>   some compilers accept it:
>
> ```
> template<typename T>
> class B {
> public:
>   class Xyz { /*...*/ };  // Type nested in class B<T>
>   typedef int Pqr;        // Type nested in class B<T>
> };
> template<typename T>
> class D : public B<T> {
> public:
>   void g()
>   {
>     Xyz x;  // Bad (even though some compilers erroneously (temporarily?) accept it)
>     Pqr y;  // Bad (even though some compilers erroneously (temporarily?) accept it)
>   }
> };
> ```
>
> This might hurt your head; better if you sit down.
>
> Within `D<T>::g()`, name `Xyz` and `Pqr` do not depend on template parameter
>   T, so they are known as a nondependent names. On the other hand, `B<T>`
>   is dependent on template parameter `T` so `B<T>` is called a dependent
>   name.
>
> Here’s the rule: the compiler does not look in dependent base classes
>   (like `B<T>`) when looking up nondependent names (like `Xyz` or `Pqr`). As a
>   result, the compiler does not know they even exist let alone are
>   types.
>
> At this point, programmers sometimes prefix them with `B<T>::`, such as:
>
> ```
> template<typename T>
> class D : public B<T> {
> public:
>   void g()
>   {
>     B<T>::Xyz x;  // Bad (even though some compilers erroneously (temporarily?) accept it)
>     B<T>::Pqr y;  // Bad (even though some compilers erroneously (temporarily?) accept it)
>   }
> };
> ```
>
> Unfortunately this doesn’t work either because those names (are you
>   ready? are you sitting down?) are not necessarily types. “Huh?!?” you
>   say. “Not types?!?” you exclaim. “That’s crazy; any fool can SEE they
>   are types; just look!!!” you protest. Sorry, the fact is that they
>   might not be types. The reason is that there can be a specialization
>   of `B<T>`, say `B<Foo>`, where `B<Foo>::Xyz` is a data member, for example.
>   Because of this potential specialization, the compiler cannot assume
>   that `B<T>::Xyz` is a type until it knows `T`. The solution is to give the
>   compiler a hint via the `typename` keyword:
>
> ```
> template<typename T>
> class D : public B<T> {
> public:
>   void g()
>   {
>     typename B<T>::Xyz x;  // Good
>     typename B<T>::Pqr y;  // Good
>   }
> };
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, this is due to the compiler's order of semantic compilation phases. It happens that, to the compiler's view, the symbol `type` is not present in any scope, because it hasn't (yet) instantiated templates, and thus, it hasn't instantiated `D` itself.

The only workaround is to force the compiler to resolve the symbol in a later phase of semantic compilation, such as with...

```
void f(typename B<T>::type) {}
```

Or, if the derived class is *not* a template, but the base class is, the compiler is *forced* to resolve/instantiate/whatever the base class first, thus avoiding any possible errors inside the derived class.

But this is not the case if *both* base and derived are templates, because the compiler will look-up a symbol for the derived in all already instantiated scopes (such as the global scope) **before** instantiating the derived template class, and if it fails, well you already know what happens with `int main(){printf("%d\n", argc);}`, no?